# Copy object properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have some custom Object definitions like:

```
var Class1 = function () { this.value = ''; };
var Class2 = function () { this.data = ''; };

Class1.prototype = {
    setObject: function () {
        for (var prop in this){
            if (typeof obj[prop] != 'undefined')
                this[prop] = obj[prop];
        }
    }
}

Class2.prototype = {
    setObject: function () {
        for (var prop in this){
            if (typeof obj[prop] != 'undefined')
                this[prop] = obj[prop];
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to have this method `setObject` by default to all clases?

Is it better to (simulate) inherit that function from the `Object` type in JavaScript or is it better to use a global function or to define it one by one?

Comment: What about Class2.prototype = Class1.prototype; ?

Comment: In your code, what is `obj`? It looks like you are trying to define default properties for your objects?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Do you want to do "cloning objects"? Objects properties may be structured objects, so you will be working with "references". You should make a special cloning method for each class.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals obj is usually a JSON object that would want to have access to the functions defined in the class. @IvanKuckir It works, but is it the best? It is not actually a cloning function it loads data from a plain object. You could clone easily with it... `function clone () { var tmp = new Class1(); tmp.setObject(this); return tmp; }`

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be using a library such as jQuery or underscore, you'll already have access to a resilient `extend` method (see [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/), and [`_.extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend)), so I would say that there's no reason to reinvent the wheel on these custom object types.

Otherwise, you can have `Class1` and `Class2` inherit from a common base class:

```
function BaseClass() {
    ...
}
BaseClass.prototype = {
    setObject: function (obj) {...}
};

function Class1() {
    ...
}
Class1.prototype = new BaseClass();

function Class2() {
    ...
}
Class2.prototype = new BaseClass();

var a = new Class1();
a.setObject({...});

var b = new Class2();
b.setObject({...});
```

Or, if those objects should not contain a common ancestor, you could define them to use the same `setObject` function reference:

```
function setObject(obj) {
    ...
}

function Class1() {
    ...
}
Class1.prototype = {
    setObject: setObject
};
function Class2() {
    ...
}
Class2.prototype = {
    setObject: setObject
}
```

Comment: It kind of breaks the class definition? or am I using wrongly? [http://jsfiddle.net/jaxkodex/C55Lc/](http://jsfiddle.net/jaxkodex/C55Lc/)

Comment: @jaxkodex, your `printMe` function is buggy (should be `str += ...`, not `str = ...`), but either way you shouldn't be rolling your own object inspector. Use `console.log` and the dev console (typically F12).

Comment: @zzzBov why using `str = str + ` is buggy? and I use console.log to check variables, but for the example print it was ok...

Comment: @jaxkodex, sorry, i misread it, either way, use the dev console, it'll give you better data. And it appears to be producing the right results.

Comment: I don't want to merge objects... I want to set the data from an object, but that is only in the current object.. say an instance `A` of `Class1` wants to take the value from an object `{ value: '123.01', date: '01/05/09'}` I'd call `A.setObject({...})` and copy only the ones defined (`value` not `date`) thats why I would use `for (var prop in this)` in the `setObject` function

Comment: @jaxkodex, oh i see now. I'd overlooked that implementation detail. In that case you'll want to stick to your custom implementation rather than `$.extend` or `_.extend`

Comment: Still, which would I use? `Class1.prototype.setObject` or `Class1.prototype = new Class();` as @IvanKuckir said or `Object.prototype.setObject`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you know that, but there are no classes or methods in Javascript. There are only objects, functions and a special property called "prototype".

The common way of simulating classes is this:

```
var Class  = function () { this.prop = "hi" };
Class.prototype.doMethod = function () { this.prop = "hi2"; };
Class.prototype.setObject: function () {
    for (var prop in this){
        if (typeof obj[prop] != 'undefined')
            this[prop] = obj[prop];
    }
}

// those classes "inherit" from Class
var Class1 = function () { Class.call(this); this.value = ''; };   
Class1.prototype = new Class();

var Class2 = function () { Class.call(this); this.data  = ''; };
Class2.prototype = new Class();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ivan showed how to inherit from an object. More information about using constructor functions and inherritance can be found here: [Prototypical inheritance - writing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711)

You can use a mixin pattern as well:

```
var mixIn=function(target,source){
  for(fn in source){
    if(source.hasOwnProperty(fn)){
      target.prototype[fn]=source[fn];
    }
  }
};
var ObjectSettable = {
    setObject: function () {
        for (var prop in this){
            if (typeof obj[prop] != 'undefined')
                this[prop] = obj[prop];
        }
    }
};
var Class1 = function () { this.value = ''; };
//... Class1.prototype stuff
mixIn(Class1,ObjectSettable);
```